# Prove that $\tau$ is a stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let $X$ be a random variable with the following distribution: $P\big(X=1\big)=P\big(X=-1\big)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Assume that: $F_{t}=\sigma\big\{sX\colon\ s\leq t\big\}$

**Task:**

Check if $\tau(\omega)=\inf\big\{t>0\colon\ tX(\omega)>0 \big\}$ is stopping time with respect to $F_{t}$.

**Solution:**

We must check whether: $\big\{\omega\in\Omega\colon\ \tau(\omega)\leq t\big\}\in F_{t}$, for every $t>0$.

Thanks to  **Kavi Rama Murthy** comment:

1. If $X(\omega)=-1$, then $\tau(\omega)=+\infty$ since infimum of empty set is eual to $+\infty$.
2. If $X(\omega)=1$, then $\tau(\omega)=0$.

How to formally show that $\tau$ is stopping time?

Comment: $\tau (\omega)=0$ if $X(\omega)=1$ and $\tau (\omega)=\infty$ if $X(\omega)=-1$ (taking the infimum of empty set to be $\infty$. This implies that $\tau$ is a stopping time.

Comment: According to your comment I have re-written my question. However, how to formally show that $\tau$ is a stopping time?

Comment: My comment tells you that $\{\tau \leq t\} \in \sigma (X) \subset \sigma \{sx:s \leq t\}$

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $0<s<t$, then
\begin{align}
\{\tau\leqslant t\}&= (\{\tau\leqslant t\}\cap\{X=-1\}) \cup (\{\tau\leqslant t\}\cap\{X=1\} )\\
&= \{X=1\}\\
&= \{sX=s\}\in\mathcal F_t,
\end{align}
and hence $\tau$ is a stopping time with respect to $\{\mathcal F_t\}$.